# creating table with char pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I want to create a table in c with char pointers but this program doesn't work and I don't know where is problem 
 
should I put '\0' at the end of string ? 

**Here is my code :**

```
void table(int n)
{
char *s,*first;
s = (char *)malloc((5*n+3)*sizeof(char));
first = s;
int i,j;
for(i=0;i<2*n+1;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<3*n+1;j++)
    {
        if(i%2==0 && j%3==0)
        {
            *s = ' ';
            s++;
        }
        else if(i%2==0 && j%3!=0)
        {
            *s = '-';
            s++;
        }
        else if(i%2==1 && j%3==0)
        {
            *s = '|';
            s++;
        }
        else if(i%2==1 && j%3 != 0)
        {
            *s = ' ';
            s++;
        }


    }
    *s = '\n';
    s++;
}
*s = '\0';
printf("%s",first);
free(s);
}
```

table like this :

```
     -- --
    |  |  |
     -- --
    |  |  |
     -- --
```

**Edit:**
after some edit in program now it run but in some cases program crash and windows stop program running .

Comment: You have `s = ' ';` but `s` is a `char *` pointer. Turn on the compiler warnings.

Comment: I fixed that but again doesn't work!

Comment: 'doesn't work' is not useful.

Comment: show me nothing even a single character

Comment: Aside: `free(s);` should be `free(first);`

Comment: I am getting some output but it has too many newlines. Time to use a debugger, etc.

Comment: You succession of `else if` tests lacks a final `else` without a conditional test.

Comment: I edit program now it print table but after that in some runs windows error that program stop working , why?

Comment: Please stop editing the question code and confusing future visitors/users who can then no longer understand the comments.

Comment: sorry, I did this to take less time for finding solution

Comment: I did this to take less time for finding solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The amount of iterations is incorrect.

I think you have more iterations than you expect. Put a counter in the iterations and you'll see.

Look:

If n=3:

- Malloc takes 18 chars.
- first `for` iterates 7 times.
- second `for` iterates 10 times.

  - total iterations is not `7+10`, it's `7*10`

You are writing out of space, aren't you?

This is the malloc you are looking for:

```
s = (char *)malloc(( (2*n+1) * (3*n+2) +1)*sizeof(char));
```

- 2n+1 for the vertical space of the square.
- 3n+1 for the horizontal space + 1 for the `\n`.
- +1 for the last `\0`.

This is the full code:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

void table(int n);
int main(void){
    table(10);
    return 0;
}

void table(int n)
{
    char *s,*first;

    s = (char *)malloc(( (2*n+1) * (3*n+2) +1)*sizeof(char));

    if(!s){
        return;
    }

    first = s;
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<2*n+1;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<3*n+1;j++)
        {
            if(i%2==0 && j%3==0)
            {
                *s = ' ';
                s=s+1;
            }
            else if(i%2==0 && j%3!=0)
            {
                *s = '-';
                s=s+1;
            }
            else if(i%2==1 && j%3==0)
            {
                *s = '|';
                s=s+1;
            }
            else if(i%2==1 && j%3!= 0)
            {
                *s = ' ';
                s=s+1;
            }
        }
        *s = '\n';
        s++;
    }

    *s = '\0';
    printf("%s",first);
    free(first);
}
```

Comment: thanks, I fix code but it gives error for n=10

Comment: I compile the exact same code and then run it but for b=10 it gives error

Comment: Compile error? runtime error? which error?
You need to help us help you.

I can run it with n=10000

Comment: runtime error that says program has stopped working

Comment: I found the error, and updated the answer.

You need to add + 1 to the `malloc` because you have `\n` in all the lines, including in the last one. So, you need to allocate 1 space more for the `\0`.

Now it should work.

To test these things I recommend you to use Valgrind, it's a great tool.